# Problema «Ha habido un error critico en tu web» al cambiar tema

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Mi problema es cuando intento cambiar el tema por defecto de wordpress Twenty Twenty por otro me sale el error:

> Ha habido un error crítico en tu web. Por favor, revisa el buzon del
> correo electronico de administracion de tu sitio para instrucciones.
>
> Aprende mas sobre la depuración en WordPress.

Pero además no me llega ningun correo.

Estoy desde un localhost, he instalado wordpress por medio de xampp. Ya he activado el modo debug, pero me salen muchos errores para solucionar cambiando el código, pero a lo mucho habré corregido un par, los demas no los entiendo. ¿Que podría hacer?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sucede con todos los temas o solo con temas especificos?

Comment: @JefferzonBol Si, con todos los temas.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica la version de PHP que esta usando el Xampp, deberias tener activa la 7.3, tambien puedes abrir la pagina de "Salud del sitio" y te dira si tienes algo que corregir a nivel de servidor, como Version de PHP, etc.

Tambien puedes, sino tienes mucha información cargada, eliminar ese wordpress y montar uno nuevo actualizado